# python subprocess - how to change dir to run command?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I've got a python script where I run a cmd using subprocess.getoutput(), and store the resulting output in a list. Now, I need to be able to have the script change to a target dir and run the command there. It should be simple, but passing the cwd arg to getoutput() is not working.

Any ideas?

Example:

```
out = subprocess.getoutput(" ".join(cmd), cwd='/my/target/path').splitlines()
```

From the doc it looks like I can easily do this with subprocess.Popen, but then it's difficult to get the output into a list of strings. I've only been able to get the results into a list of binary strings.

Comment: `cwd` is not a valid parameter for `getoutput` so you get an exception, not a list. Is your problem with `cwd` or getting a list of `bytes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess.getoutput` is a [Legacy Shell Invocation Function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#legacy-shell-invocation-functions). It doesn't take `cwd` argument and returns a tuple of `(status, output)`. You've got several problems before you even get to the list of `bytes`.

When python runs a program, it doesn't know what encoding its output is going to have you need to supply that somehow. Assuming the encoding is `utf-8', the basic operation is

```
mylist = []
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, cwd='/my/target/path')
for line in mylist:
    mylist.append(line.decode('utf-8'))
proc.wait()
```

In this implementation, anything written to `stderr` just goes to your programs `stderr`. Notice also that I kept the command as a list and didn't do `shell=True`. There are several helper functions that do some of the work for you, but that's pretty simple already.